# How do I color a specific word in a string in Rust?

Tags: rust

I have a Rust project.
It's purpose is to take 2 arguments, a search term and a file name, and print the contents of the file with the search term in the file colored red.
How do I achieve this?
Below is the code.

```
use std::env;
use std::fs::File;
use std::io;
use std::io::prelude::*;
use std::process;

fn main() {
    let args: Vec<String> = env::args().collect();
    let input_args: InputArgs = InputArgs::new(&args).unwrap_or_else(|err| {
        println!("Problem parsing arguments: {}", err);
        process::exit(1)
    });
    println!(
        "Searching for {:?} in file {:?}.",
        input_args.search_term, input_args.file_name
    );
    run(&input_args);
}

fn run(input_args: &InputArgs) -> io::Result<()> {
    let file = File::open(&input_args.file_name)?;
    let reader = io::BufReader::new(file);
    for line in reader.lines() {
        let line = line?;
        println!("{}", line);
    }
    Ok(())
}

struct InputArgs {
    search_term: String,
    file_name: String,
}
impl InputArgs {
    fn new(args: &[String]) -> Result<InputArgs, &str> {
        if args.len() < 3 {
            return Err("Please enter at least 2 arguments.");
        }
        let search_term: String = args[1].clone();
        let file_name: String = args[2].clone();
        return Ok(InputArgs {
            search_term,
            file_name,
        });
    }
}
```

I have found libraries that can color the entire string but not one that can color only specific words.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have found the solution to my problem.
Below is the code.

```
use colored::Colorize;
use std::env;
use std::fs;

fn main() {
    let args: Vec<String> = env::args().collect();

    let search_term: &str = &args[1];
    let file_name: &str = &args[2];

    println!(
        "Searching for term {} in file {}.\n",
        search_term.red().bold(),
        file_name.purple().italic()
    );

    search_file(search_term, file_name)
}

fn search_file(search_term: &str, file_name: &str) -> () {
    let content: String = fs::read_to_string(&file_name).expect("\nCould not read the file!");
    for word in content.replace("\n", " \n").split(" ") {
        if word.contains(search_term) {
            print!("{} ", word.red().bold())
        } else {
            print!("{} ", word)
        }
    }
    println!("")
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Most of the crates that color a string actually are capable of coloring individual words. Take for example [colored](https://docs.rs/colored/latest/colored/):

```rust
use colored::Colorize;

fn main() {
    println!(
        "{} {} {}",
        "or use".cyan(),
        "any".italic().yellow(),
        "string type".cyan()
    );
}
```

If you were trying to build a string, you could also use `format!` instead of `println!` to build the actual string instead of directly outputting it, like so:

```rust
use colored::Colorize;

fn main() {
    let mut string = format!(
        "{} {} {}",
        "or use".cyan(),
        "any".italic().yellow(),
        "string type".cyan()
    );

    string.push_str(&*"! hello".cyan().to_string());

    println!("{string}");
}
```

Comment: Note that coloring is platform-dependent. `colored` requires an ANSI-compatible terminal. I.e. most Unix/Linux/MacOSX environments should work as well as Windows Powershell, but notably the regular windows console won't work.